# Is the Content-Type charset not exposed from HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpclient, content-type

I'm converting some code from using `HttpWebRequest` to `HttpClient`. One problem I'm having is getting the charset from the content-type response header.

When using `HttpWebRequest`, the charset is exposed in the `HttpWebResponse.CharacterSet` property, like this

```
using (WebResponse response = await this.webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
{
     string characterSet = ((HttpWebResponse)response).CharacterSet;
```

You can also get to it from `WebResponse.ContentType` property or from the content-type header in `HttpWebResponse.Headers`.

Using `HttpClient`, the charset seems to be missing from the `ContentType` header.

Here's the code that I'm using for `HttpClient`:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead))
    {
        charset = httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet;
```

The CharSet property is always `null`.  `HttpResponseMessage` has a `Headers` property but it doesn't contain the content-type header.  `HttpResponseMessage.Content` also has a Headers property, which does appear to contain the content-type header, but that header shows `"Content-Type: text/html"` - it doesn't have the charset portion.

Using the first approach with `HttpWebResponse` for the same url, I get the charset portion of the Content-Type header.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

I was looking to emit the charset inside a HttpResponseMessage and since your question is the first on google and that i found the answer several pages below, here is the code

```
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName;
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("CodePage", Encoding.UTF8.CodePage.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get it this way:

```
var contentType = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `Content-Type` header returned from the server would have to contain the 'charset' like `'text/html;charset=UTF-8'` in order for it to show up in the `CharSet` property. Checking the raw response in a tool like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) may help.

And thanks for helping me find where the `Content-Type` header was buried in the `HttpResponseMessage` object!

Answer (score 1):

Since the Content-Type can be an array of types, you may want to check any of them for validity, but this is assuming server was written correctly and does not intermingle types and char sets

```
var isJson = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").Any(x=>x.Contains("json"));

var isCharsetUTF8 = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").Any(x=>x.Contains("charset=UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient intentionally does not expose charset. Precisely, it can not. It is asynchronous, so when it connects to a server, it waits until response. It is not aware of charset or anything else except TransferEncoding in HttpResponseMessage which does not contain anything except "chunk" or "zip".

So to get an encoding of the response body, we should read it to a variable and then look thoroughly.